# Line bundle associated to classifying map

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, line-bundles

I am trying to understand the correspondence between complex line bundles on $B$ and homotopy classes of maps $[B , BU(1)]$.

One direction I can do. That is, if we have a map $f: B \to BU(1)$, we can construct a line bundle as the pullback of the universal line bundle $EU(1) \times _{U(1)} \mathbb{C} \to BU(1)$ along $f$.

However, I can't find a source on how to go the other way around. That is, if we have a complex line bundle $E \to B$, how do we get a (homotopy class of) map(s) $B \to BU(1)$?

Equivalently, we need a circle principal bundle on $B$. The best way I can think of doing this is "removing" the zeroes from $E$, quotienting by the action of $\mathbb{R}^{>0}$ and then we get a $U(1)$-principal bundle on $B$, but I am not sure about this since I feel like we are losing information by removing the zeroes and quotienting.

Comment: Fix a metric on $E$ and look at the unit sphere bundle. This a principal $U_1$-bundle. Alternatively work with the principal $\mathbb{C}^\times$-bundles that results from removing the zero section from $E$. The homomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\times\rightarrow S^1=U_1$, $x\mapsto x/\|x\|$, induces a homotopy equivalence $B\mathbb{C}^\times\simeq BU_1$.